# Can't figure out ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException error in Stack(push)

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm creating a stack program and ran into this error, `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`, when I try to push.
It gets the `topofindex` value and data from the `main`.
When I input the array size to use a `scanner`, even the value is 3, it still ran into the error.

```
public class ArrayBaseStack {
private int topIndex = -1;
        private int inputArrNum;
        private int inputData;
        private int stackArr[] = new int[inputArrNum];
public void push(int inputData) {
            this.inputData = inputData;
            topIndex++;
            stackArr[topIndex] = inputData;
        }
public void pop() {
            if (isEmpty()) {

            }
            else {
                System.out.println(stackArr[topIndex]);
                topIndex--;
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayBaseStack arrayBaseStack = new arrayBaseStack();            
        arrayBaseStack.inputArrNum = sc.nextInt();



        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBaseStack.inputArrNum; i++) {
            String stackOrder = sc.next();
            int data =0;
            if(stackOrder.equals("push")){
                data = sc.nextInt();
                arrayBaseStack.push(data);
            }
            else if (stackOrder.equals("pop")){
                arrayBaseStack.pop();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong Direction.");

        }
```

Result:

```
3
push 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time your `ArrayBaseStack` class is initialized, `inputArrNum` is null so this line:

`private int stackArr[] = new int[inputArrNum];`

creates a new array with a size of `0`.

You should change `ArrayBaseStack` to have a constructor that takes the array size, then initialize the array before any other operations are performed. This will prevent the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you're currently getting. E.g.

```
...
public ArrayBaseStack(int size) {
   stackArr[] = new int[size];
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you :) I changed my code below


    public ArrayBaseStack(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.topIndex = -1;
        stackArr = new int[this.capacity];
    }

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputArrNum = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayBaseStack arrayBaseStack = new ArrayBaseStack(inputArrNum);  

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArrNum; i++) {
            String stackOrder = sc.next();
            int data = 0;
            if (stackOrder.equals("push")) {
                ....
            }